# Python problem importing functions from another file in same directory

Tags: python, importerror

My import statements are:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from description_category import my_recode
from category_dictionary import code2_category, q_cat_category
from datetime import date
```

The files description_category.py and category_dictionary.py are in the same directory as the current program.  The error I get is:

```
  File "D:\My Documents\AccountingPersonal\inspectRecodedDescriptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from category_dictionary import code2_category, q_cat_category

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'category_dictionary'
```

I think I am using the right syntax.  It seems strange that the reference to the second module was flagged and not the one to the first.  As an ugly fix I copied the second script into the first, removed the reference to it and ran it.  It worked.

I am using:

- Spyder version: 5.2.2 None
- Python version: 3.9.7 64-bit
- Operating System: Windows 10

```
 Directory of D:\My Documents\AccountingPersonal

03/05/2022  02:31 PM             1,045 categoryDictionaries.py
03/07/2022  07:47 AM             1,943 category_dictionary.py
02/01/2022  11:24 AM               946 cleanNames.py
03/03/2022  01:41 PM               777 compare_original_copy.py
03/07/2022  07:47 AM            11,740 description_category.py
02/17/2022  02:01 PM             1,662 fixMintAccounts.py
02/07/2022  05:53 PM             2,539 getAmazon.py
03/04/2022  08:42 AM             6,689 getChase.py
03/04/2022  08:23 AM             6,587 getChaseData.py
02/20/2022  03:18 PM             9,240 getMint.py
02/03/2022  01:37 PM             2,784 getQuickenData.py
03/07/2022  08:00 AM             3,065 inspectRecodedDescriptions.py
02/08/2022  10:22 AM             1,893 investigateChaseDups.py
02/07/2022  04:26 PM               471 MoreInspectionChaseDups.py
02/17/2022  02:03 PM             1,662 prelimMintAccounts.py
02/04/2022  12:10 PM             1,222 qkn_category2.py
01/29/2022  11:28 AM               787 quickenCategories.py
01/30/2022  06:28 PM             5,187 readPass2.py
01/26/2022  02:33 PM             1,672 testCSVs - Copy.py
02/01/2022  01:04 PM             4,738 testCSVs.py
02/11/2022  12:06 PM             1,030 toyproblem.py
03/06/2022  05:57 PM                 0 xinit.py
03/06/2022  05:57 PM                 0 __init__.py
```

Comment: Just to be sure, can you go in `D:\My Documents\AccountingPersonal`, type `dir` in a command line terminal and copy the output here ? (by editing your original message)

Answer (score 3):

Make an empty file called **init**.py in the same directory as the files.
This tells python the directory is a package and it is okay to import from there.

Then proceed to import as:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from .description_category import my_recode
from .category_dictionary import code2_category, q_cat_category
from datetime import date
```

Comment: I followed your directions and got the message:  ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package from the first import.  I renamed the empty file to __init__.py (since the documentation used that name) and again had the same error.

Comment: the file name should be "_ _ init_ _.py" (double underline before and after init)

Answer (score 0):

High likely, python is not being able to find the module to import because it maybe is being executed from another directory.

To solve this:

1. Open a terminal and `cd` into the script's folder, then execute python from there.
2. Run this code in your script to print from where python is being executed from:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

3. For example, if the code is located at `C:\folder\test.py` , open a terminal and type

```
python3 C:\folder\test.py
```

or (if `python3` shows error):

```
python C:\folder\test.py
```

It will give an initial output of the code.

4. Now type

```
cd C:\folder
python3 test.py
```

After `cd`ing to the exact folder, if you have other modules in the folder, importing them after this should not be a problem.

Comment: Here is the result, after import os and before importing my two scripts: 
D:\My Documents\AccountingPersonal Thats the directory that the scripts are in.

Comment: Seems okay. And then please follow the steps from 3. And let me know the results.

Comment: Running python from cmd did not show the print output (even though I confirmed that it was there with a type ... | more command).  The error however remains.

Comment: It is unusual. I have also tested this approach and it is working fine on my Windows 10 pc. Though I am using VS Code and python 3.7.

Comment: Can you please retry the approach answered by NGV above but with the file name being `__init__.py` (exact double underscores by the side of init like this) ?

Comment: The last entry in the question has a list of the files. The last is indeed _ _ init _ _.py. (with two underscores before and after.)